# What's the equivalent of flexigrid's params in jqgrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, flexigrid

What's the equivalent of flexigrid's params in jqgrid?

```
$('#bsDetail').flexigrid({
    @* refactor, avoid parameters in url 
    url: '/Area/Location/Details?id=@(Guid.Empty.ToString())', *@

    url: '/Area/Location/Details',
    params : [ { name : 'id', value : '@Guid.Empty' } ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use default HTTP GET (`mtype:'GET'`) the jqGrid equivalent will be

```
$('#bsDetail').jqGrid({
    url: '/Area/Location/Details',
    postData: { name : 'id', value : '@Guid.Empty' }
    // ...
});
```

Moreover if the URL parameters are no constants you can consider to use `postData` having functions as the properties (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819));